# Test GeneratorExecutionContext

Tags: c#, xunit, sourcegenerators

I'm writing a source generator and, as part of that, I need to read the `.csproj` file.

I can get that file by using the `build_property.ProjectDir` in the `GeneratorExecutionContext.AnalyzerConfigOptions.GlobalOptions` and I've written a couple of extension methods to make working with this easier:

```cs
public static class GeneratorInitializationContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetProjectDirectory(this GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        context.AnalyzerConfigOptions.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.ProjectDir", out string? projectDirectory);
        if (projectDirectory is null) throw new("Can't find project directory");
        return projectDirectory;
    }

    public static string GetProjectFile(this GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        string   projectDirectory = context.GetProjectDirectory();
        string[] files            = Directory.GetFiles(projectDirectory);
        string   projectFile      = files.Single(f => f.EndsWith(".csproj"));
        return projectFile;
    }
}
```

Now, these work fine. However, I'd like to get them under some test coverage.

Unfortunately, I can't work out how to create a `GeneratorExecutionContext` to test against. Its only constructor is internal and its `AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider` property doesn't have a setter.

How can I approach this?